# Fuzzywuzzy columns

Tags: pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I am creating a new column based on pandas, string contains and regex. The example:

```
df.loc[df['random_words'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*SEA)(?=.*MAN)(?!.*WOMAN)(?!.*CHILD)'),'Person'] = 'Fisherman'
```

There is a lot of words to be inserted in the code and a lot of new data continuously to be integrated in the code. Descriptions in every documents to be searched are slightly different per document. There are about 50 possible outcome keywords, which btw remain constant.
Also, There is a lot of overlap between words to be looked for and I  would like to take it into account possible typo's as well. To make the process more effective and less time consuming I am now opting to use Fuzzy Wuzzy and a Levenshtein ratio instead of regex.
Would anybody have a suggestion on how to achieve something similar to the regex above output using Fuzzy Wuzzy (or other Machine learning/ NLP mechanisms for that matter)?

Currently I am trying the following function, which compares the possible outcome words to the Excel list to be scanned (but that does not work and does not assign the best possible match):

```
comparison = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1["A"],df2[B"]]).to_series()
def metrics(tup):
    return pd.Series([fuzz.ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*tup)],
                     ['ratio', 'token'])
```

Comment: Are multiple outcome keywords possible? For example, if a document matches the regex for both `fisherman` and some other outcome? And when you say a lot of new data is continuously to be integrated, do you mean more documents, or more possible words in your regular expression?

Comment: Yes, if a cell contains several matches, additional columns can be created. 'Fisherman' could be a target word, but also 'old fisherman' (which would still have to be fitted in a single cell), but also  for example 'old fisherman, incapable' would then result into two columns (based on comma separation btw).  Different documents have different descriptions which still can match to the same keywords, ..this indeed means more words have to be integrated in the regex..